# Trying to find the quickest (least costly) way to loop values in from a .csv through two tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, csv

The application I am building allows a user to upload a .csv file, which will ultimately fill in fields of an existing SQL table where the Ids match. First, I am using LinqToCsv and a `foreach` loop to import the .csv into a temporary table. Then I have another `foreach` loop that loops the fields from the temporary table into an existing table where the Ids match. The only way I have gotten this to work consistently and successfully is nesting the second foreach loop within the first:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadValidationTable(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
    {
        var inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = ',',
            FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
        };
        var cc = new CsvContext();
        var filePath = uploadFile(csvFile.InputStream);
        var model = cc.Read<Credit>(filePath, inputFileDescription);

        try
        {
            var entity = new TestEntities();
            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount,
                    CreditInvoiceDate = item.CreditInvoiceDate,
                    CreditInvoiceNumber = item.CreditInvoiceNumber,
                    CreditDeniedDate = item.CreditDeniedDate,
                    CreditDeniedReasonId = item.CreditDeniedReasonId,
                    CreditDeniedNotes = item.CreditDeniedNotes
                };
                entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc);

                var idMatches = entity.Authorizations.ToList().Where(x => x.Id == tc.Id);

                foreach (var number in idMatches)
                {
                    number.CreditInvoiceDate = tc.CreditInvoiceDate;
                    number.CreditInvoiceNumber = tc.CreditInvoiceNumber;
                    number.CreditInvoiceAmount = tc.CreditInvoiceAmount;
                    number.CreditDeniedDate = tc.CreditDeniedDate;
                    number.CreditDeniedReasonId = tc.CreditDeniedReasonId;
                    number.CreditDeniedNotes = tc.CreditDeniedNotes;
                }
            }
            entity.SaveChanges();
            entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE TemporaryCsvUpload");

            TempData["Success"] = "Updated Successfully";

        }
        catch (LINQtoCSVException)
        {
            TempData["Error"] = "Upload Error: Ensure you have the correct header fields and that the file is of .csv format.";
        }

        return View("Upload");
    }
```

The issue is speed. It takes about 1 minute and 49 seconds to search through an SQL table of 7000 entries, match the ids, and fill in the fields.

So, I looked at this and thought that the second loop really didn't need to be nested. I switched up the code like so:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadValidationTable(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
    {
        var inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = ',',
            FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
        };
        var cc = new CsvContext();
        var filePath = uploadFile(csvFile.InputStream);
        var model = cc.Read<Credit>(filePath, inputFileDescription);

        try
        {
            var entity = new TestEntities();
            var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload();
            foreach (var item in model)
            {

                tc.Id = item.Id;
                tc.CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount;
                tc.CreditInvoiceDate = item.CreditInvoiceDate;
                tc.CreditInvoiceNumber = item.CreditInvoiceNumber;
                tc.CreditDeniedDate = item.CreditDeniedDate;
                tc.CreditDeniedReasonId = item.CreditDeniedReasonId;
                tc.CreditDeniedNotes = item.CreditDeniedNotes;
                entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc);
            }

            var idMatches = entity.Authorizations.ToList().Where(x => x.Id == tc.Id);

            foreach (var number in idMatches)
            {
                number.CreditInvoiceDate = tc.CreditInvoiceDate;
                number.CreditInvoiceNumber = tc.CreditInvoiceNumber;
                number.CreditInvoiceAmount = tc.CreditInvoiceAmount;
                number.CreditDeniedDate = tc.CreditDeniedDate;
                number.CreditDeniedReasonId = tc.CreditDeniedReasonId;
                number.CreditDeniedNotes = tc.CreditDeniedNotes;
            }
            entity.SaveChanges();
            entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE TemporaryCsvUpload");

            TempData["Success"] = "Updated Successfully";

        }
        catch (LINQtoCSVException)
        {
            TempData["Error"] = "Upload Error: Ensure you have the correct header fields and that the file is of .csv format.";
        }

        return View("Upload");
    }
```

This time around, it only took 19 seconds to complete. A vast improvement on the first. But when I checked the database, only one row of the 7 that should match was filled in. Can anybody spot a reason why the second code block would not be filling in all the rows it should be? Or a better way to optimize the first block? Thanks!

Comment: The reason the second loop doesn't work is that you set `tc` inside your first loop, but your matches are defined after the loop with `var idMatches = entity.Authorizations.ToList().Where(x => x.Id == tc.Id);`, so you are only searching for the `Id` of the last item in the first loop. In terms of performance, I would suggest just importing the entire CSV to the temp table, and running an update statement. Relational databases are designed for this kind of set base operation. The fastest way may be to use a StreamReader, and SqlBulkCopy, although less elegant than LinqToCsv, it will be faster.

Comment: Makes sense. Could you see any possible changes for slight performance improvements if I continue with this method?

Comment: Still trying to figure out how I can adjust this so it doesn't have to iterate through the database as much. If there are 1000 items in the csv and 2000 in the permanent table then it takes a lifetime